# Running the Same Formula From Different Cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a formula that is really complex that I want to use in many places. I put this formula in one master tab as just text in a cell then I want to run it from other tabs. I want to use the text from the cell as my formula.

I build this complex text with several inputs on the sheet. It's built the same for each sheet, just different input at the top of the sheet to change the factors and actual calculations.

As an example, and this isn't my calculation, but suppose I had this text (not formula) in Sheet1 cell A1:
concatenate(a1,a2,a3)

Then, in Sheet2, I want to run this. I have tried Indirect and cannot quite seem to get it to work:
=Indirect(Sheet1!A1)
And I have tried other combinations with quotes apostrophes, etc... Somehow, I'm either getting the combination of those wrong or entirely on the wrong track.

Answer (score 0):

posible only with script:

```
function onEdit() { 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Master Sheet');  
var src = sheet.getRange("A1");   // The cell which holds the formula
var str = src.getValue();  
var cell = sheet.getRange("C5");  // The cell where I want the results to be
cell.setFormula(str);             // Setting the formula.
}
```

and your A1 needs to be:

```
="=CONCATENATE(A1, A2, A3)"
```

Comment: I now have A1 as you've given as I'm not using a script. To reference this, just to get this working, I go to another cell in the same sheet and have:
=INDIRECT(A1)

And, in A1, what I really have is:

Comment: @Geo like it was said. this is possible to solve only with script

Comment: I keep hitting Return when I wanted to edit. My apologies. What I was trying to change this comment to was this:

I now have A1 as you've given as I'm not using a script. To reference this, just to get this working, I go to another cell in the same sheet and have:
=INDIRECT(A1)

And, in A1, what I really have is a formula that builds a formula from other formulas:
=concatenate("=""=sumifs(",F2,",",F3,", B7", ")""")

I think going back to your example I'm understanding when I'm getting !REF on this. Thanks for the help.